# Integrate pdo_cassandra in Windows

Tags: php, pdo, cassandra

I am trying to access cassandra from PHP PDO as below,

https://code.google.com/archive/a/apache-extras.org/p/cassandra-pdo

Where can i download **pdo_cassandra** extension for windows? Can anyone please let me know on this

Comment: Why don't you use the official PHP driver ? https://t.co/UmPnJXnQFx

Comment: i want to integrate with Laravel.. so i can use their Eloquent Model if i get it in pdo_cassandra